# ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: error:00000005:lib(0):func(0):DH lib

Tags: mysql, ssl, database-administration

I am trying to run mysql delete script on .bat file in between of the execution getting exception as

ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: error:00000005:lib(0):func(0):DH lib

PLease sugest. Its not happending everytime.

for query : SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%ssl%'; getting below result as
have_ssl =YES and have_openssl=YES